# Email clients adding some extra pixels below TD with background image

Tags: email, background, padding, newsletter

I am facing a problem making a newsletter in Gmail and Outlook.

I've got a table with some TD's that contain a background-image:

```
<tr>
    <td width="401" height="99" background="http://www.domain.com/bg_left.jpg"></td>
    <td width="149" height="99" background="http://www.domain.com/bg_right.jpg"></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried adding the background images trough [this method](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/).
But with both ways I've got the following behaviour in Gmail and Outlook.

[image]

In both examples there is added some extra padding where the image is repeated. 
Someone familiar with this problem? I couldn't find anything about this by myself.

Thanks instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gmail, you can remove the  margin at the bottom of your images by changing the `display` property to `block` will prevent that.

Unfortunately, it seems that Outlook.com doesn't allow you to set the `display` property of images, but if you add a `div` (which is a `block` by default) with the same height as the `img`, [as described here](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/two_fixes_for_image_spacing_in_outlook_web_app_owa), you'll get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, but in my situation the images are used as background on the TD's. This is because there must be a dynamic text on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use VML to display background images on a table in Outlook. [Here is a tool in Campaign Monitor](http://backgrounds.cm/) for doing exactly that.

Firstly, confirm your table cell `height=""` to the same as your image. Assuming it is, it looks like the cause might be your content expanding the table height past the specified height. Gmail has a habit of stretching the text line-heights, so if you have a `&nbsp;` underneath your subheader, this may be the cause. Remove that and it should fix it.

If that doesn't work, post the entire table and I'll take another look.